# Parallel (Aff) execution with concurrent limit?

Tags: purescript

What is the way(s) of implementing parallel execution with concurrent processes limit in terms of Aff? I believe there is no method in std libs and didn't find a good full answer on this.

`parSequenceWithLmit :: Array (Aff X) -> Int -> Aff (Array X)`

`Aff X` calcs should be made in parallel, but not more the given N concurrent calcs. So it starts N cals, when one is accomplished, the next one (of the left) is started.

Comment: Could you please clarify what "concurrent processes limit" mean in this context? Perhaps describe a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I added specifics in OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sort of thing a good mechanism is [`AVar`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-avar/4.0.0/docs/Effect.AVar#t:AVar), which is a blocking mutable cell. It can be conceptually thought of as a one-element blocking queue.

**First**, an `AVar` may be either empty or full. You can create an empty one with [`empty`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-avar/4.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff.AVar#v:empty), and then you can "fill" it with a value using [`put`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-avar/4.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff.AVar#v:put). The useful bit here is that, when you call `put` and the `AVar` is already "full", `put` will *block* until it's empty again.

**Second**, you can read the value using [`take`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-avar/4.0.0/docs/Effect.Aff.AVar#v:take), which will return you the value, but leave the `AVar` empty at the same time. Similarly to `put`, if the `AVar` is empty, `take` will block until it's full.

**So what you can do with it** is the following:

1. Create a single `AVar`.
2. Fork off N processes, each of which will `take` a value from that `AVar` and process  it, then loop. Forever.
3. Have an orchestrator process, which will iterate over the whole sequence of work and `put` work items into the `AVar`.

When all work processes are busy, the orchestrator process will push another value into the `AVar`, and then will try to push the next one, but will become blocked at this point, because `AVar` is already full. It will remain blocked until one of the work processes finishes its work and calls `take` to get the next work item, leaving the `AVar` empty. This will unblock the orchestrator process, which will immediately push the next work item into `AVar`, and so on.

The missing bit here is **how to stop**. If the work processes just do an infinite loop, they will never quit. When the orchestrator process eventually runs out of work and stops filling the `AVar`, the work processes will just block forever on the `take` calls. Not good.

So to fight this, have two kinds of work items - (1) actual work and (2) command to stop processing. Then have the orchestrator process first push all the work items, and once that is done, push N commands to stop. Optionally you can push N+1 commands to stop: this will guarantee that the orchestrator process blocks until the last worker has finished.

**Putting all of this together**, here's a demo program:

```hs
module Main where

import Prelude

import Data.Array ((..))
import Data.Foldable (for_)
import Data.Int (toNumber)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.AVar (AVar)
import Effect.Aff (Aff, Milliseconds(..), delay, forkAff, launchAff_)
import Effect.Aff.AVar as AVar
import Effect.Class (liftEffect)
import Effect.Console (log)

data Work a = Work a | Done

process :: Int -> AVar (Work Int) -> Aff Unit
process myIndex v = do
  w <- AVar.take v
  case w of
    Done ->
      pure unit
    Work i -> do
      liftEffect $ log $ "Worker " <> show myIndex <> ": Processing " <> show i
      delay $ Milliseconds $ toNumber i
      liftEffect $ log $ "Worker " <> show myIndex <> ": Processed " <> show i
      process myIndex v

main :: Effect Unit
main = launchAff_ do
  var <- AVar.empty
  for_ (1..5) \idx -> forkAff $ process idx var

  let inputs = [100,200,300,300,400,1000,2000,101,102,103,104]
  for_ inputs \i -> AVar.put (Work i) var

  for_ (1..6) \_ -> AVar.put Done var
```

In this program my work items are just numbers, which signify the number of milliseconds to sleep. I'm using this as a model of how "expensive" each work item is to process. The program output will be something like this:

```
Worker 1: Processing 100
Worker 2: Processing 200
Worker 3: Processing 300
Worker 4: Processing 300
Worker 5: Processing 400
Worker 1: Processed 100
Worker 1: Processing 1000
Worker 2: Processed 200
Worker 2: Processing 2000
Worker 3: Processed 300
Worker 3: Processing 101
Worker 4: Processed 300
Worker 4: Processing 102
Worker 5: Processed 400
Worker 5: Processing 103
Worker 3: Processed 101
Worker 3: Processing 104
Worker 4: Processed 102
Worker 5: Processed 103
Worker 3: Processed 104
Worker 1: Processed 1000
Worker 2: Processed 2000
```

Comment: Thanks that's very useful as always!